# REST implementation for CodeIgniter example is returning a blank page

Tags: php, rest, api, codeigniter-3

I am following the instructions on setting up a REST API with codeigniter following these instructions by Phil Sturgeon [here](https://philsturgeon.uk/codeigniter/2009/06/03/REST-implementation-for-CodeIgniter/)

I have copied the REST_controller.php,rest.php and example.php into the respective folders listed in the tutorial and also included the Format.php file in the libraries folder. I have also edited the autoload.php file to include

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'html');
```

When I try to test the link provided

```
 http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/api/example/user/id/1
```

I receive a blank page and when I check the response it is also empty.
I am able to reach the landing page.

```
 http://localhost/codeigniter/
```

I can't seem to figure out what else I need to do.

Comment: WSOD == turn `error_reporting` on/up.

Comment: Can you post your code? It is hard when we are not seeing your code based on your explanation given..